# Does engine oil get old and go bad?

Tags: oil, oil-change, boat

Does engine oil actually go bad from just sitting within an engine that's not getting use? I feel conventional motor oil has been sitting underground for millions of years prior to being extracted and refined. But I have a 1995 Mercruiser 350 (small block Chevy) marine engine with under 200 hours on it that hasn't had its oil changed since 2004. Am I doing significantly more damage to this engine by not changing the oil right now before running it this weekend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer ....   **NO !!**

Now this is one of those seriously contentious topics that people will chime in from all walks of life, experience, and voodoo.

I will speak [yell] my piece, and put on my Nomex undies:

Oil goes "bad" from two things:

1. The long chains get broken down due to wear.  But ask any tribologist with an ounce of morals, and they will tell you that modern engine oil is sufficient to last MANY thousands of miles, perhaps 10-20K. (I get that you speak hours - I'm too lazy to translate that to knots.) And that's good old dinosaur juice.  Modern synthetic compounds have wonderful properties, and might last twice as long as the organic stuff.  In fact, with the exception of point #2, the right synthetic might last 50,000 miles. (x 0.868976 knots)
2. BUT BUT BUT....   Oil gets **dirty**.  Little particles of soot and combustion products and small insects and detris and debris and schmutz and water accumulate in your oil storage "area".  A really good oil filter [e.g. Oberg] might filter down to 5 micron or less, but require frequent cleanings.  Hence you only see this type of filter in racing and special applications.

   2A.  So what?  Some of that dirt is abrasive.  None of it is helpful.  It is circulated under pressure.  Now imagine that your very expensive synthetic oil is circulating little tiny abrasive bits all around those critical lubricated interface points.  Doesn't matter how much the "excipient" [big word] costs, what you have created is a cutting fluid - no matter how expensive.  The size of the little cutter buggers is only limited by your oil filter.  And your standard oil filter is a balance between longevity and particle size.

So So So?

Oil gets **dirty**.  (Did I yell that yet?)  AND **OIL GETS DIRTY AT THE SAME RATE** WHETHER IT'S USED "Wolfshead" OIL FILTERED THROUGH WONDERBREAD, OR ULTRA-SYNTHETIC DERIVED FROM SIBERIAN ANT GLANDS AND COSTS $5000/ounce.

(whew.  okay, I took a breath)

So... to "answer your actual question" [cough] The one thing that does **NOT** make oil dirty is non-use.  Unless you are parked in a desert monsoon or something.  That's not even a thing.  It just doesn't happen.

*I know such statements are gonna get me some negative attention.*  But to summarize, oil does not "spoil", and non-use certainly doesn't sever the long chain molecules.

Yes, moisture that accumulates from combustion by-products should be vaporized off once in a while, but oil is not hygroscopic, and extended storage will not add bad things.  The only issue is "rundown", or long term storage having the oil seep out of critical wear points... which makes that first "cold start" of the season perhaps detrimental.  However, again, this is NOT a function of the oil, oil type, or change frequency.

[*So could you stop yelling and have a point?*]

The bottom line is that you will be much better served starting your boat motor every month for a minute or two in drydock. Even without cooling, if your unit draws seawater. This will "re-wet" the important surfaces with oil and prevent terrible "cold-start" damage.  If you can't do that, I'd suggest a oil pressure revival by removing all the spark plugs and cranking long enough to achieve oil pressure.  Or squirt some oil in the cylinders before start-up.  But EITHER way, **it's not the age of the oil, it's the lack of oil in critical places.**

The marketing idea that "oil spoils! MUST replace every six months!" is a bit of marketing horsefeathers that makes me rant like I'm doing now.  Oil doesn't get moldy, it doesn't spoil, and it doesn't loose lubricity from non-use.  Just like you mentioned, these are very stable molecules that can exist for millenia (the very reason why you shouldn't pour waste oil on the weeds).

But from 2004?  I'd put fresh oil in it just for the exercise, and crank with spark plugs out and a few squirts in each cylinder.  Again, it's not the age of the oil, it's the fact all the important bits have gone "dry" in 13 years.

On Edit:  [I realized later you said the oil had not been changed since 2004, not that you haven't run the boat since then.  All the better.]

YMMV.  Best of luck...

Comment: Yeah, I had the boat out 3 times this year already and I want to take it out again this weekend. I'm big on maintenance, but it's about an hour each way to get to the storage and I really want to drain the oil while the engine is still hot. Thanks for the writeup, I've always been skeptical of the 'change your oil every X months', but thought maybe there was something I was missing.

Comment: "every x months" might be retentive, but 13 years?  Age aside I book-keep an hour as 100 miles on a marine engine, so you also have maybe 10,000 "miles" on the oil. Run it this weekend and change it hot Sunday afternoon.

Comment: I sort of agree (but your conversion implies an average of 87 knots/hour over those 100 hours... that is one fast boat!) Point taken, however, and maybe a reasonable change interval is 50 hours.  My post was a long-winded attempt to answer the OP's question.  And I absolutely agree: if 100 hours made the oil filthy, then it was in there too long.  My assertion is only that if you set a say, 50 hour change interval, it doesn't matter if it takes 5 days or 5 years to accumulate the hours.

Comment: I knew the previous owner and the boat had a meticulous maintenance schedule prior to sitting. The oil likely only had 5-10 hours on it. But I feel like the load on a boat engine is similar to driving a car uphill its entire life at 60-70 MPH at 3k RPM. I'll likely move to changing it once a season and it'll likely have under 50 hours each season.

Comment: @SteveRacer  the theory is that the load on the engine of a typical ( planing ) boat at a given speed is much higher than on a car engine at that speed, so running your boat at 30 is comparable to running a car at 100.  Obviously a gross generalization but it gets you in the ball park.

Comment: @agentp Agreed.  I'm a *huge* proponent of oil changes, perhaps too many/too often (but I heat my shop with waste oil in New York winters, so all is not lost.)  My real pick of nit is some sort of Byzantine "rulebook", written by bean-counters and marketing slime that insists oil changes every six months, implying that oil "spoils".   Or even the reverse twist: a little tiny NASCAR icon pixie standing on your air cleaner that says **THIS** oil can last a *whole year* ... and yet it's the same stuph and yet costs four times as much!

Comment: What about oil additives? The stuff oil companies put in their oil. Do they have stable shelf lives of "millenia" also?

Comment: Bah @Xen2050 ...  I'm sure any oil additive isn't "bad"... But I'm also very sure that it's much cheaper just to change it.  Why resort to voodoo when you can just change the fluids and be done?  "Vodun" ... [cough]  I've a long history of bully pulpit screams that can be simply distilled to this:  Change your oil.  Get the dirt out.  Some oil is better than others.  BUT THEY ALL GET DIRTY AT THE SAME RATE...  (sorry for the shouting.  Sort of...)

Comment: You're essentially talking about the shelf life of engine oil (unused & clean), and you literally said "*Oil doesn't get moldy, it doesn't spoil, and it doesn't loose lubricity from non-use... these are very stable molecules that can exist for millenia*" and now you're saying *"just to change it"*? It's clean. Calm down and think a little about what you're typing. If you don't know the shelf life of oil additives (and therefore don't know oil's true shelf life) then just say so.

Comment: I'm calm.  No, I don't think detergents and the like, zinc, moly, wear additives, etc. will affect the overall *shelf life*.  None of these are VOCs. If it's unused, it's unused.  My point was to make it clear that no matter what the additive package, oil that's being *used* gets dirty at the same rate.

Comment: I have no idea if you're right (I hope you are), but regardless, I must take a moment to compliment you on an excellent rant! :)

Comment: I don't have knowledge in the field or an opinion on the matter, so here are some different opinions: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/how-often-to-change-oil-if-vehicle-gets-under-1500-miles-per-year  and  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/13247/is-it-mandatory-to-change-oil-once-a-year

Comment: @RockPaperLizard If you read those answers carefully, there's a general confusion about "oil" and "oil plus additives".  Yes, additives deplete - in other words, they get *used*.  That doesn't mean they rot away just sitting there.  Oxidation and neutralization of combustion products are important, but they are chemical reactions that occur with the *heat of running the engine*.  I have not seen a single piece of hard evidence that claims oil or any additive component breaks down even with non-use.

Comment: Think of it this way:  Would you throw away a jug of synthetic because it's been sitting in your garage for a year?  What evil magic transpires if I pour it into a crankcase instead, but never start the engine?  If the engine temperature cycles due to weather, I could see condensation forming - but that is why I suggest running an engine once in a while.  You don't have to change it because the oil (or additives) are simply old.  Old and USED, yes.  Just sitting there, no.  The only hard and fast "twice a year" suggestions come from oil companies and OEMs.  Go figure!

Comment: @SteveRacer Thanks for your insightful comments. To me, what you say makes sense... but it's not too hard to convince someone with my limited knowledge in the field. :)  I have a vehicle that I use about 1000 miles/year, and start every 2-3 weeks.  I've been considering doing an oil change, but by my understanding of your statements, there is no need.  Based on what you say, I think I may consider waiting another year... I sure hope you're right! :)

Comment: @RockPaperLizard  I'm glad you are not bucking against my *very* opinionated spin.  BUT...  I will say this:  Change your oil. Just to get the dirt out.  I think this is a fine plan.  Just use SFI rated oil in the right viscosity combination for your vehicle.  You don't need Siberian Ant Gland magic; just keep it clean.  This might seem counter to what I preach, but in reality: it's cheap enough... especially if you don't subscribe to miracle synthetics.  I worry much more about your "filter" than I do about your oil. Avoid Allied Signal/Fram and get a nice Wix or Mann.

Comment: Which you can pour the Wallmart "wolfshead" or whatever cheap store brand you want.  Change every 3000-4000 miles, HOWEVER LONG THAT TAKES you.  (sorry for the shouting)   [It's kinda my thing]

Comment: @SteveRacer I'm currently at 700 miles and 16 months.  (And starting it every 2-3 weeks for a short 10-30 mile roundtrip drive).  Are you recommending changing the oil  and filter now or waiting until 3000-4000 miles (perhaps another 2-3 years)?

Comment: <b>SteveRacer says</b> "...but oil is not hygroscopic, and extended storage will not add bad things." **Steve is incorrect.** Oils are absolutely hygroscopic...those with additives even more so. Depends on the type, formulation, etc. Short start-stop cycles and/or extended lack of use will contaminate lubricants and alter their composition which will, in turn, affect engine components directly and indirectly.

Comment: @CriticalThinker water contamination from condensation (non-use) will sink the the bottom of the sump.  Oil is not hygroscopic at the level of alcohol or glycol brake fluid.  Take the same amount of motor oil and moonshine with the same humidity exposure, and check the level of water contamination.  Some of that condensed water could be emulsified with *use*, but at the same time enough heat will boil it out.  Ever heat margarine? I agree totally about short drive cycles, but not about extended storage.  The effects are different by magnitudes.  Oil and water are largely immiscible.

Comment: That said, moisture contamination from combustion products is an entirely different animal.  The particle sizes and intense mechanical mixing will certainly create "margarine" which is not a good lubricant, degrades film strength and additives, and potentially enables oxidation of metal parts and bearing surfaces.

Comment: As **synthetic** means synthetic, it couldn't be from siberiant ants. I think that would be called **animal based motor oil**. Any on the market? I heard blubber oil is good?

Comment: @lofihelsinki  I did say "derived".  Modern synthetics are often created from dino "animal" base stocks (crude, natural gas, coal), and processed (Fischer-Tropsch) so the chains get much longer.  Although I'm not aware of any current supply of super synthetic derived from *Myrmica rubra* base stock, I am quite certain it's very expensive...