# How often and for how long a motorbike (Honda CBR 919 RR Fireblade) needs to run in order to be healthy?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, performance, preventive-maintenance

I love my motorcycle but I have been thinking about coming to work by bicycle sometimes.

My [motorcycle is a 1998 Honda CBR 918RR Fireblade](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/63854/45815)

I currently use it every week day. On Mondays, after being parked for 2 days it is still good, provide I let her warm up first (I actually do this every day).

My question is:
How often I need to use my motorbike in order to keep her running smoothly?

Let's not consider the winter months, to be more objective.

I currently service her each about 6,000 km
Mostly I ride in the city (London that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a 30 minute ride in every 3 weeks is sufficent to keep the battery going. Depending on how long you are going to let it sit and depending on the condition in which the bike is kept there might be other advices too. For example tires may develop some issues if you are keeping it at the same position for a long time. Similarly there may be issues caused by moisture. You should probably check the literature for motorcycle winterizing as there will be issues that apply in general. Here is a reference:

[Leaving Bike unused for 3 months](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/62581/leaving-bike-unused-for-3-months/62666#62666)

However if you ride it even once a week and do your maintanance regularly (that is either yearly or by the kilometer whichever comes first) I can not think of a reason why a machine would not run.

Edit: If you are not servicing the bike yourself there may be some important items that an ordinary mechanic might ignore. It is in fact a general practice where I live. You should also keep a close eye on those stuff. Misadjusted valve clearances are probably a bigger issue than not riding the bike once in a while.